# Error while importing the framework

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, core-telephony

My app deals with phone call.So I added coretelephony framework to my project.But when I try to import the framework to my appdelegate,I get the error "No such file directory" Can any one find the solution for that.I use xcode 4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI after you add core telephony framework then add

`#import <CoreTelephony/CoreTelephonyDefines.h>`
to your appDelegate.h file

It will solve your problem.

Comment: Is there any possibility to import the whole framework instead of importing header by header to my project?